# Routing Rails 3 with string parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to be able to direct

```
/samplecontroller/search
```

with a :q parameter. How do I do this in rails 3? I currently have

```
 match 'samplecontroller/:search' => 'samplecontroller#search'
```

but all it gives in rake:routes

```
/samplecontroller/:search(.:format)   {:action=>"search", :controller=>"samplecontroller"}
```

The controller expects

```
def search
    @search = Post.search(:include => [:comments]) do
      keywords(params[:q])
    end
  end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
match 'samplecontroller/search' => 'samplecontroller#search'
```

Comment: But how does params :q get passed in?

Comment: Your request will be like `/samplecontroller/search?q=searchquery`.

Answer (score 0):

In routes.rb:

```
 match 'samplecontroller/search' => 'samplecontroller#search'
```

Your version said that :search was a parameter for the route.  Removing the leading colon tells it to match that whole string literally.